# improper inner join result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an update, I want to do in another table by comparing the multiple fields in two tables.

```
UPDATE [Route tbl]
INNER JOIN UniqueZips 
ON
 ([Route tbl].[WINDOW 5] = UniqueZips.[WINDOW 5]) AND  
 ([Route tbl].[WINDOW 3] = UniqueZips.[WINDOW 3]) AND 
 ([Route tbl].[WINDOW 4] = UniqueZips.[WINDOW 4]) AND 
 ([Route tbl].[WINDOW 2] = UniqueZips.[WINDOW 2]) AND 
 ([Route tbl].[WINDOW 1] = UniqueZips.[WINDOW 1]) 
SET 
 [Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips]![CODE]
```

The code above however does not work even when I change this to a select to see what output I get I get zero fields.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that you have any records with all those matches?

Comment: If your select statement is not returning any data, then your update query is not going to work, as Remou asked, do you have records that can be matched on all 5 criteria?

Answer (score 1):

With the exception of this line,

```
[Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips]![CODE]
```

Which should be

```
[Route tbl].CODE = [UniqueZips].[CODE]
```

your query looks good. Are you sure that your data actually has matching rows?